# Azure Storage SDK: managed disk copy (using SAAS URL) from one region to another Azure region

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

If this data is transferred using SAS URL of managed disk from one region to another region does it still travel on internet?

I am using Azure Java SDK storage APIs.

Answer (score 0):

No, cross region traffic doesnt leave Azure internal networks. Doesnt matter how it originates.